# Send redirect url with @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY)

Tags: spring

I am using an exception class for `@ResponseStatus` , but I am not able to figure out how do I send redirect URL in case of 301 Permanently Moved error ?

Exception class:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
public class ResourceMovedPermanentlyException extends RuntimeException{

}
```

Comment: What do you mean you are using an exception class for @ResponseStatus? Please show some code

Comment: @geoand made an edit, please check

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Spring's [RedirectView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html)

```
RedirectView rv = new RedirectView(url);
rv.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
rv.setUrl(url);
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(rv);
return mv;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add the url with the simplified exception handling you are using.

Check out vzamanillo's solution (use it in a class that is annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and a method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`).
For the whole story of Spring MVC exception handling check out [this](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) blog post

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear. I suppose you want to redirect to a page in case of `ResourceMovedPermanentlyException` being thrown. In that case you could use the `ExceptionHandler` annotation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceMovedPermanentlyException.class)
public String handleException(final Exception e) {
    return "redirect:/the/target/page";
}
```

Alternative implementation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceMovedPermanentlyException.class)
public String handleException(final RuntimeException e,
                  final HttpServletRequest request, // this can be omitted if not needed
                  final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    response.sendRedirect("/the/page/or/url/you/need/to/redirect");
}
```

You also could store the redirect URL into the exception:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceMovedPermanentlyException.class)
public String handleException(final ResourceMovedPermanentlyException e,
                  final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    response.sendRedirect(e.getRedirectUrl());
}
```

See the [ExceptionHandler JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) for more details about the options available for the exception handler method.